# Растягивание textarea во все стороны

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Как можно предоставить пользователю возможность растягивать элемент `textarea` во все стороны? Пример ожидаемого результата показан на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 минут гугления привели меня на страницу [плагина для jquery](http://www.jquery-css.com/resize-all-direction-resizable)
Позволяет ресайзить элемент во все стороны.

Пример вызова:

```
$("selector").resizable({

    side : { Default value : true to each one
        top : true | false,
        left: true | false,
        bottom : true | false,
        right : true | false
    },
    disabled : true | false, //call to disable or enable
    aspectRatio : true | false | number, //that is width / height (ex 1.5)
    distance :: number, //sensible band-width in pixels
    grid : false | [xValue, yValue], //false or grid magnet [x, y]
    maxHeight: number, //default value:null
    maxWidth: number, //default value:null
    minHeight: number, //default value:10
    minWidth: number, //default value:10

});
```

Сам плагин если не нашли лежит по ссылке [тут](http://www.jquery-css.com/js/magic.min.js)

Саму текстарию, скорее всего, вам не удастся апгрейдить до такого вида, поэтому делаете див с атрибутом `contenteditable="true"`

Кладете его в див, на который потом наложите плагин.
Если вам нужен именно такой конечный вид, который изображен на вашем скрине, то кладете еще 8 абсолютных дивов внутрь. Каждый из этих дивов должен иметь бекграунд квадратика. 4 угловых дива и 4 дива на стороны. Дивы по сторонам должны иметь атрибут бекграунда по середине, чтобы всегда быть в центре.

Должно получиться что-то типа этого:

html:

```
<div class="resizable">
    <div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="lt"></div>
    <div class="rt"></div>
    <div class="rb"></div>
    <div class="lb"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="l"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.resizable{position: relative; border: 1px dashed grey;}
.editable{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}

.lt{background-image: квадратик; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
// по аналогии все угловые дивы кладете по углам

.t{background-image: квадратик; background-position: center center; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;}
// по аналогии все сайдовые дивы кладете по сторонам
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('.resizable').resizable();
});
```

Даже такой ответ лучше, чем писать, что тут никто работу за вас не сделает, не правда ли?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь имею представление о том, как это можно реализовать. Конечно же лучше, в том ответе не больше ответа на заданный вопрос, чем в пустоте.

Comment: А что мешает вместо `<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>` оставить textarea'ю?

Answer (score -1):

Это делается скриптами. И не на `textarea`, а на блоке с атрибутом `contenteditable`.

Answer (score -2):

У textarea c высотой всегда были проблемы, но можно соорудить такое:

```
<textarea style="min-height:500px; width: 100%;">
    Test text
</textarea>
```

Comment: не, мне надо, чтобы пользователь мог растягивать и влево и вправо и по углам.

Comment: Ну тогда смотри пример: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea

Comment: вы вообще читали мой вопрос? мне нужно во ВСЕ СТОРОНЫ. картинку даже привел в пример, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: @Artie Lay: естественно что пример не полный, никто за вас всю работу здесь делать не будет.